# How can I resolve the memory error while calculating pairwise distance of a high dimensional numpy array and converting into square form?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a 16GB RAM laptop. I am using 195159 x 153 data from [Home Credit Default Risk | Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/home-credit-default-risk/data?select=HomeCredit_columns_description.csv). I am trying to calculate pairwise distance of each point and put it in square form.

```
import scipy as sp
pdist=sp.spatial.distance.pdist(X,metric='sqeuclidean')
Corig = sp.spatial.distance.squareform(pdist,checks=False)
```

I am getting memory error while calculating spatial.distance.pdist for the entire data [error message 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6YTP.png)

Tried out on 100K samples, I am able to calculate the pairwise distance (pdist) but getting error while converting into square form [error message 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/As7lK.jpg):

Comment: This is a very large matrix, it make sense you are OOM, I would suggest trying to split this into several calculations.

Comment: Why are you doing it? Probably you can merge the calculation and the next step then you don't need to store all the distances.